# How to unit test a function with a dependency (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, oidc-client-js

I'm new to unit testing and have some got basics down. However, I'm trying to test a method. This method calls a function which is part of the oidc-client.js. It basically signs a user in.

> spec file

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AuthCallbackComponent } from './auth-callback.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';


fdescribe('AuthCallbackComponent', () => {
  let component: AuthCallbackComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AuthCallbackComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [ AuthCallbackComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AuthCallbackComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

> component.ts

```
import { UserManager,User,UserManagerSettings,WebStorageStateStore} from 'oidc-client';

  manager = new UserManager(this.getClientSettings());


  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.completeAuthentication();

  }


  completeAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      this.setUser.next(this.user.profile);
      this.onLogin.next(true)
    });
  }



  getClientSettings() {
    return {
      authority: environment.authority,
      client_id: environment.client_id,
      redirect_uri: environment.login,
      post_logout_redirect_uri: environment.logout,
      response_type: 'code',
      scope: 'openid profile email phone address',
      filterProtocolClaims: true,
      loadUserInfo: false,
      accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 60,
      silentRequestTimeout: 10000,
      includeIdTokenInSilentRenew: true,
      automaticSilentRenew: true,
      silent_redirect_uri: environment.silent_redirect
    };
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how I go about testing this. When I run the test I have I just get ' No state in response'. I want the test to pass and maybe some ideas on how to test the completeAuthentication()

Comment: Few comments: `1.` what is `this.manager` ? Can u show your full component code and let me know  ` 2.` your `completeAuthentication(): Promise<void>` seems incorrect because this function is not returning any promise, rather its resolving in itself by using `.then` . So, that seems incorrect. Provide me more code of component and I'll try to help you

Comment: If you are new to `karma` and `jasmine` , may be this article would help you to get the taste of it https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7

Comment: Have you solved your problem and how have you done

Comment: Help me please !

Answer (score 0):

One tool for testing code you have no control over is [Sinon's `stub` object](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/), which can allow you to mock out the desired behavior of the 3rd party dependency.

There isn't much to go off of in the question without seeing the source code you are trying to test, but I hope the example documentation in the Sinon project will be sufficient for your use case.